# sobre-escritura de datos en un array Java

Tags: java-8

buenas tengo el siguiente codigo

```
public void iniciar() {
    int i;
    int eum;
    for (i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
        lista[i] = new Carnet();
        lista[i].capturar();
        lista[i].getimage();
        lista[i].visualizar();
        eum = i;
        System.out.println("el objeto se guardara en la posicion "+ eum);
        System.out.println("objeto #"+eum+"/"+lista[i].getProyecto());
        System.out.println("objeto #"+eum+"/"+lista[i].getNombre());
        System.out.println("objeto #"+eum+"/"+lista[i].getCodigo());
```

el problema es que cuando en otro metodo intento buscar el valor de una variable para un objeto que esta en la lista, siempre toma los valores de el ultimo objeto creado, añado imagen con el codigo y el output en terminal para evidenciar el problema

edit:

los dos metodos que utilizan el arreglo son:

```
 public void iniciar() {
    int i;
    int eum;
    for (i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
        lista[i] = new Carnet();
        lista[i].capturar();
        lista[i].getimage();
        lista[i].visualizar();
        eum = i;
        System.out.println("el objeto se guardara en la posicion "+ eum);
        System.out.println("objeto #"+eum+"/"+lista[i].getProyecto());
        System.out.println("objeto #"+eum+"/"+lista[i].getNombre());
        System.out.println("objeto #"+eum+"/"+lista[i].getCodigo()); 

    }

}
public void ver() {
    nCarnet = (Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("que carnet desea ver?"))-1);
    System.out.println("prueba de datos guardados");
    System.out.println("obj #0 "+lista[0].getProyecto());
    System.out.println("obj #0 "+lista[0].getNombre());
    System.out.println("obj #0 "+lista[0].getCodigo());
    System.out.println("obj #1 "+lista[1].getProyecto());
    System.out.println("obj #1 "+lista[1].getNombre());
    System.out.println("obj #1 "+lista[1].getCodigo());

    lista[nCarnet].visualizar();
}
```

el output de el metodo ver es:

```
el objeto se guardara en la posicion 0
objeto #0/ejemplo
objeto #0/carlos
objeto #0/456
el objeto se guardara en la posicion 1
objeto #1/carrera promedio
objeto #1/marselo
objeto #1/741
prueba de datos guardados
obj #0 carrera promedio
obj #0 marselo
obj #0 741
obj #1 carrera promedio
obj #1 marselo
obj #1 741
```

Comment: No coloques imágenes agrega el código en su lugar. Modificas el arreglo en otro lugar?

Comment: no, simplemente esos dos unicos metodos usan ese arreglo, esta definido al inicio de la clase asi: Carnet[] lista = new Carnet[2];

Comment: En el método `ver`, todos los `System.out.println` imprimen el mismo objeto `lista[0]`, en vez de `lista[nCarnet]`. ¿Será eso?